# Training Set for Face Recognition

Tags: java, image-recognition, face-recognition, training-data

Can someone please explain to me **what training set in context of face recognition means**?

I have been reading journals and I often see pages like

> In the experiments, five samples of each person chose randomly are
>   used to form the training set, and the remaining samples are used for
>   testing.

Thanks

Comment: how about "data to train the recognition algorithm"? Looks pretty clear

Comment: Can you please explain what it means by "train the recognition algorithm"? 
Does it mean like the 5 samples of a person in that training data is used to produce a feature vector for that  person?
I am really lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A [training set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training_set), in the context of face recognition, is a way to discover relationships between different data sets/the same data set in different contexts.  For face recognition, if I give an algorithm seven different pictures of my face and eight different pictures of my friend's face, the idea for the algorithm is to find similarities between the seven pictures of my face/eight different pictures of my friend's face, such that a new picture of either my friend or me could be identified.

See [facial recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_recognition_system) on Wikipedia for more.

The input to an algorithm is a list of tagged pictures, tagged meaning a tuple with a picture and the identity of the individual.

For example:

```
train = [(img1, 'Louis'), (img2, 'Louis'), (img3, 'John'), (img4, 'John')]

img_rec = algorithm(train)
```

Then, you apply your trained algorithm to identify untagged images.

```
test = [img5, img6, img7]

for i in test:
    img_rec(test)
```

Which will (ideally) identify the person in the images, assuming you have adequate training data/a good algorithm.

**EDIT:** Regarding your above comment, yes!  Sometimes.  Different algorithms use different ID methods.  [A good site detailing the four main algorithms in use now](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/evalfacerec/index10.php).